# Not able to get message of empty or required field using Joi npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules

Joi package Version: ^17.6.0

I'm trying to get the error of the array of object keys. Reference Image of Joi Validation:

[image: Reference Image of Joi Validation]

Json Data:

[image: Json Data]

In this picture, I'm validating most of the fields using Joi, However when I try to validate an array of objects then I get the locations array message. Though, The empty or required is in items of the array.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Actually I'm not really sure of the problem, can you add the data that you want to validate here and paste the code as well.

Comment: @Andrei I've updated my question with the information, you asked me for.

Comment: Better to add the actual code and json data as text/snippet in the question so we can try it.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `array.min(1)` validation to specify that at least 1 item is required.
Also there doesn't seem to be any `array.empty` error so you need to use `array.min`.